# Как через js высчитывать количество дней до определенной даты?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день есть такая структура

```
<div class="pg-info">
      <div class="pg-info__top">Бронирование открыто до <span id="date">01.03.2019</span></div>
      <div class="pg-info__bottom">осталось ВСЕГО <span class="number">45 </span><span>ДНЕЙ</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Как сделать что бы JS сам высчитывал сколько дней осталось до данной даны. Дата в таком формате 01.03.2019( Берется из Базы данных) но если требуется можно поменять вид даты ( ex. 01/03.2019)

Comment: и зачем это делать на js ?

Comment: Какие методы можно еще сделать? Надо что бы человек ввел дату. она выводилось а автоматом выводилось количество оставшихся дней

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если дата всегда будет в подобном формате, то можно вот так

```js
var dateDOM = $("#date").text().split(".");
var date = Date.parse(dateDOM[2] + "-" + (dateDOM[1]) + "-" + dateDOM[0]);
var days = (date - Date.now()) / 86400000;
days = parseInt(days)
days = days + 1;
$('#day-last').text(days)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pg-info">
  <div class="pg-info__top">Бронирование открыто до <span id="date">01.03.2019</span></div>
  <div class="pg-info__bottom">осталось ВСЕГО <span id="day-last" class="number"></span><span> ДНЕЙ</span>
  </div>
</div>
```